# How to get two different version of executable in the same iPhone? using Xcode

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, xcode4, xcode4.3

kindly excuse if my question is very basic.

I am using Xcode 4.3.3, and when i run the application i get the icon and with bottom line with HTH. Now I have fixed something in the code, and would like to run in the iPhone, but i do not want the previous executable file in the iPhone i.e.: HTH should also be present. For that what changes do i have to do in the Xcode, so that i get one more executable in the device?

I tried changing the Targets name:

```
1. single click in target name
2. Close the Xcode, and restart,
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the bundle identifier in `info.plist`

Comment: My bundle identifier is something like : demo:${PRODUCT_NAME:rfcsomethign}, it is ok if i name to something else?, It is anyway related to recreation of provisioning certificate?

Comment: yes insert a new bundle identifier. When you will publish the app you must use the new bundle identifier.

Comment: That means each time i give new fix, and if i would like to keep all versions in the mobile, then i should include all bundles in the provisioning certificate right?

Comment: Do you want to take different version of app only in development, right? If yes, it is not necessary to insert the bundle identifier in your provision certificate.

Comment: Yup, but still i need to send the ipa file to the customer, in that case, it is definitely required if i am not wrong?.